# SQL returns SQL as result. How do i run the returned SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

using the crosstab method to dynamically pivot a hstore thats suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94717/dynamically-convert-hstore-keys-into-columns-for-an-unknown-set-of-keys). Is there any way i can instantly run the sql returned or is there  way to have a function that would call the original crosstab then run the sql to return the pivoted table as the only result instead of running two queries ?

so when i run this query

```
    SELECT format(
   $s$SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT h.id, kv.*
       FROM   hstore_test h, each(hstore_col) kv
       ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
   , $$SELECT unnest(%L::text[])$$
   ) AS t(id int, %s text);
   $s$
 , array_agg(key)  -- escapes strings automatically
 , string_agg(quote_ident(key), ' text, ')  -- needs escaping!
   ) AS sql 
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT key
   FROM   hstore_test, skeys(hstore_col) key
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

it returns a result that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT h.id, kv.*
       FROM   hstore_test h
       LEFT   JOIN LATERAL each(hstore_col) kv ON TRUE
       ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
   , $$SELECT unnest('{key1,key2,key3}'::text[])$$
   ) AS t(id int, key1 text, key2 text, key3 text);
```

what i want to do is either with a function or another query wrapped around the first one. return the results of the second query and use that returned data to build a materialized view

Comment: can you add some more information with your query, sample data and exact problem

Comment: @AkhileshMishra done

Comment: You could use something like [query_to_xml](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING) to run the SQL statement. Or [create](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/query-to-json/) a similar function to return the query result as JSON

Comment: If you are using `psql` you could use `\gexec`